# ggplot How to select values from two different colums?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, charts, subset

I have a `.csv` file which has 3 parameters for each item. If the item is `"apple"`, the 3 values are:

- "Area harvested"
- "Yield"
- "Production"

I don't know how to plot these Apple rows with only the "Production" value

This is my code, but it plots the 3 values:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/....data.csv",
  encoding = "ASCII", header = TRUE, 
  sep = ","
)


ggplot(subset(df, Item == "Chillies and peppers, green"),
             aes(x = Area, y = Y2014)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6) +
  coord_flip()

view(df)
```

this is the .csv [link to csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yXXLdZSOpddw0EQNN6EP5oun9Vd3Dzse/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `geom_col` is a nice way to do `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the data before calling ggplot, like this

```
df %>%
    filter(Item == "Apples",
           Element == "Production") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(Area, Y2014),
             stat = "identity", width = 0.6) +
  coord_flip()
```

NOTE: You can also sort the results for a better visualization using
`reorder(Area, Y2014, FUN = abs)` instead of simply `Area`.

```
df %>%
    filter(Item == "Apples",
           Element == "Production") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(reorder(Area, Y2014, FUN = abs),
                 Y2014),
             stat = "identity", width = 0.6) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Just that I am looking for! I have a question. What´s meaning the part of FUN = abs?

Comment: The function by which you want to sort the data, in this case the absolute value. You could also use Sum, mean, max, log, or basically any function, even designed by you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have `dplyr` loaded let's use it, specifically `filter`

```
europe %>% 
  filter(Item == "Apples",
         Element == "Production") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Area, y = Y2014)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]